# What adjective can I use for progressively layered music?

Tags: single-word-requests, music

I've been looking online for a word to describe progressively layered music.

What I mean is, for example, say a composition begins with drums, then some other instrument gets added (say, violin), then another, and another. For example, say, the [main theme of *3:10 to Yuma* (2007)](https://youtu.be/UKIoTq69h_c?si=qXuwMyArq6tefL2v).

The closest I could find on the web was "intensify" or "heighten", but I don't think that accurately describes it. In fact, even the use of the word "layered" in the question might be entirely wrong.

Comment: Early results in a Google search for ["lay a drum track" + layering](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=lay+a+drum+track+layering) show that the term is widely used for building up a recording, at least in the production of  certain music genres. But this is not the usage you want a term for. All I can find is "... all the instruments successively join with spirited and brillant effect".

Comment: You might call it increasing [texture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_(music))

Comment: Thank you for all your responses guys, I think I'll go with the 1 answer here. It's precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: Belongs on [music.se] -- may be a duplicate there.

Comment: Even if you accepted the single single-word answer, I feel like you already had a great answer yourself, 'progressively layered'. Single words are overrated.

Comment: This might be late as a response but I need to say that you're right. Now when I think of it, if I am writing this anywhere, a reader is more likely to understand progressively layered than 'staggered'.

Comment: I'd like to add that I discovered a word that might be suitable for this. In case anyone wondered or is looking for a word other than staggered, it is 
'Concinnity' which means: the skillful and harmonious arrangement or fitting together of the different parts of something. Came across this yesterday so thought I should add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When instruments enter one at a time, their entrances are described as **staggered**.
>   
>   [music.stackexchange.com](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/14286/25597)